# PyAudio Multichannel Not Recognized from Focusrite 18i20

Tags: python, audio, streaming, playback, pyaudio

I'm pretty new to code so I'm trying to understand a lot, so sorry if I'm unaware. I am running a script which listens to the inputs of a multichannel (8 channel) Focusrite 18i20 interface (3rd gen). I'm using the blocking method instead of the callback method (I think).

- Python version: 3.11.4
- PyAudio version: 0.2.11
- Torch version: 2.1.1+cu118
- Right now, the interface takes the audio in through each of the 8 mic channels on the interface (yes I've checked the mics are working and that there's feed by running a simple multi-input through a DAW).
- Then, the script runs and it playsback/streams the live audio to the stereo headphone port on the laptop. It works great, but ONLY on channels 1 and 2, not on channels 3 through 8.

Here's some of the logic:

Audio Stream Setup:

```
if read_from_file == True:
    wf = wave.open(audio_path, 'rb')
    stream = paudio.open(
        format=paudio.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
        channels=output_format, rate=wf.getframerate(), output=True)
elif read_from_file == False:
    istream = paudio.open(format=format_audio, channels=channels, rate=sr,
                          input=True, frames_per_buffer=input_chunk,
                          input_device_index=input_device)
    stream = paudio.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=2, rate=sr,
                         frames_per_buffer=input_chunk, output=True)
```

Live Streaming and Playback:

```
while len(data) > 0 and time.time() < end_time:
    if channels == 8:
        numpy_data = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.int16)
        stereo_data = mix_down_to_stereo(numpy_data)
        if normalize == False:
            data = stereo_data.astype(np.int16).tobytes()
        else:
            processed_data = compress_and_normalize(stereo_data,
                                                    threshold=-0.1, ratio=4.0,
                                                    normalize_scale=0.5)
            scaled_data = np.int16(processed_data * 32767)
            data = scaled_data.tobytes()
    stream.write(data)
    if read_from_file == True:
        data = wf.readframes(chunk)
    elif read_from_file == False:
        data = istream.read(input_chunk)
```

Closing the Audio Stream:

```
if read_from_file == True:
    wf.close()
stream.close()
paudio.terminate()
```

I've ensured all my drivers are up to date on the interface as well as reset factory defaults on the interface just to be sure (and then tested the audio input again to make sure I wasn't doing something funky). Is there a reason I get silence and absolutely no audio on channels 3 through 8? Is PyAudio compatible with multi-channel support?

I've also tried creating a simple script like this:

```
import pyaudio
import wave

FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 8
RATE = 48000
CHUNK = 1024
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
FILENAME = "test_recording.wav"

audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()

# Start Recording
stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS, rate=RATE, input=True,
                    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)

# Stop Recording
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
audio.terminate()

# Save the recorded data as a WAV file
wf = wave.open(FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(audio.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()
```

This outputs an 8 channel file to listen to. When I pull up the file in RX10 (iZotope)/Pro Tools, I see nothing but silence on channels 3 through 8.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Oh my gosh, I'm an idiot. I figured it out. Just set the interface format to "8 channel" instead of "2" in your Windows settings under the playback device settings.